# How to use Riverpod generator and Firebase Auth together

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am learning Riverpod generator and I can't seem to find any tutorial of how to use it with Firebase Auth to manage the authentication state of your app, all of them are outdated

I was thinking to use a Provider that returns a stream and then use the result of the stream to either navigate the user to the main menu or the login page, If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it as I want to make sure im using best practices.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.